# jaxb, can I use @XmlJavaTypeAdapter with @XmlElements?

Tags: annotations, jaxb, marshalling, xmladapter

Given the following annotations

```
@XmlElements({
 @XmlElement(name = "first", type = First.class),
 @XmlElement(name = "second", type = Second.class),
 @XmlElement(name = "third", type = Third.class),
 @XmlElement(name = "fourth", type = Fourth.class),
 @XmlElement(name = "fifth", type = Fifth.class),
 @XmlElement(name = "sixth", type = Sixth.class),
 @XmlElement(name = "seventh", type = Seventh.class)})
private List<Dimension> dimensions = new ArrayList<>();
```

And because of some funny legacy logic, I need to provide an adapter for Third.class.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ThirdAdapter.class)
public class Third implements Dimension
```

However, ThirdAdapter never seems to be called. Is @XmlJavaTypeAdapter compatible with @XmlElements? Or is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

This appears to be a bug in the JAXB [reference implementation](http://jaxb.java.net/).  It was also a [**bug**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=347026) in [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy), but we have fixed it in our EclipseLink 2.4.0 stream.  You can download a release candidate from the following location:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/milestones.php

**jaxb.properties**

To use MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping for a solution in the standard JAXB library, but if I find any more bugs I will definitely give moxy a try. Right now this is the only problem that I've had and I was able to cleanup the code to remove the need for the adapter.

Comment: @PresidentComacho - MOXy is a standard JAXB (JSR-222) library passing all the same Java EE compliance tests as the reference implementation.

Comment: Is this problem fixed with the current jaxb implementation supplied with Java 7_40? I didn't find a bug track entry for this bug. Do you know if ever a bug tracker entry was created?